# alias to print list of paths

Tags: shell, alias, tcsh

I am trying to create a convenience alias that should print the paths in list and tells me if the current path is in the list or not

```
printf "%s\n" `python -c "import os ; print '\n'.join ( os.getenv ( 'PATH' ) .split ( ':' ) ); print 'Current path in paths:' ,  os.getcwd() in os.getenv('PATH').split(':') "`
```

If I try to create an alias of this it shows badly placed (),s , secondly the line Current path in paths is getting printed in newline!!!

Also it would be useful if its possible to do just in shell script rather than taking advantage of python..., but I am only familiar with python.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Escaping double quotes with tcsh alias](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/382734/escaping-double-quotes-with-tcsh-alias)

Comment: What command are you using to create the alias?

Comment: I am just trying to save this file .bash_profile `alias printf "%s\n" `python -c "import os ; print '\n'.join ( os.getenv ( 'PATH' ) .split ( ':' ) ); print 'Current path in paths:' ,  os.getcwd() in os.getenv('PATH').split(':') "``

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
alias inpath 'echo $path ; echo "Current path in paths: `echo $path | xargs -n1 realpath | grep -c $cwd`"'
```