# tcsh - how to escape dollar sign in alias definition

Tags: grep, alias, tcsh

to remove files ending with a tilde `~` I have come up with the following command:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f | grep '~$'
```

I will then pipe this to `xargs` and then `rm`

I am having issues defining this command as an alias. I think the issue is with the dollar sign. I am trying:

```
alias clt "find . -maxdepth 1 -type f | grep '~$'"
```

but I get an `Illegal variable name` response.

If I try to escape both `~` and `$`:

```
alias clt "find . -maxdepth 1 -type f | grep '\~\$'"
```

I get `Variable name must contain alphanumeric characters`

Same thing if I try to escape only one of the two chars.

What is the correct way (and possibly, why)?

Comment: unless you have directory names ending with `~`, why not simply use `rm *~` ? if you do need `find`, use `find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*~'` and `find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*~' -exec rm {} \;`

Comment: LOL your solution works like a charm!
Honestly I don't know how I ended up with that line. Still, curiosity remains as to what the correct syntax would be.

Comment: after experiments and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/382734/escaping-double-quotes-with-tcsh-alias I think this should help... `alias clt 'find . -maxdepth 1 -type f | grep '\''~$'\'`

Comment: Yep! That works, although I yet have to wrap my mind around the rules in the answer you linked. Basically, there is an 'unquote' operation that saves the day if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Escaping double quotes with tcsh alias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/382734/escaping-double-quotes-with-tcsh-alias)

Comment: Sundeep, I think your  suggestion would be more clear if you decoupled some of the quotes with some extra  space like this: `alias clt 'find . -maxdepth 1 -type f | grep '   \''~$'\'`