# Alias for awk command

Tags: awk, tcsh, quoting

How do I create an alias for awk command in

```
awk '{$1="";$2="";$3="";$4="";$5="";print}'
```

in tcshrc ?

I tried like this:

```
alias crd='awk '\''{$1=\"\";$2=\"\";$3=\"\";$4=\"\";$5=\"\";print}'\'''
```

but did not work

Comment: clean approch would be to create a function in your rc file.Dont go with alias

Comment: `did not work` is the worst possible problem description. `Dear mechanic, my car did not work - now tell me how to fix it`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to escape single quotes within single quoted strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1250079/how-to-escape-single-quotes-within-single-quoted-strings)

Comment: @PS. .. a function would certainly be the approach in bash, but **tcsh** is a little more limited in that regard -- as well as being a bit more flexible for aliases.

Comment: @ghoti never got chance to work on tcsh,thanks for info :)

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice this had [tag:tcsh]; you want a different duplicate, but this is almost certainly a duplicate still.

Comment: @tripleee this might be one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/382734/escaping-double-quotes-with-tcsh-alias

Comment: Depends if the problem is a syntax error or summoning Cthulhu or something in between. So far the OP isn't sharing...

Comment: I agree with needing more information from OP, but I would suggest holding back downvotes and give OP a chance to edit the question...

Comment: @Sundeep .. I agree with giving the OP a chance. In addition, we should be cognizant that while the OP is having quoting challenges, the actual solution to hid underlying problem may be more along the lines of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10693608/1072112). If we treat the question as a programming one rather than a shell syntax one, we probably do SO a favour in the long run. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem may just be that your backslash finger is too heavy. Double quotes *inside the single quoted string* do not need to be escaped unless they're part of a double-quoted string that is inside the single quotes.

But it may also be that you're confusing the **bash** `alias` command with the **tcsh** `alias` command. Bash notation looks like:

```
alias thing=command
```

whereas tcsh looks like:

```
alias thing command
```

Note the subtle difference. :-)

The following generates no errors for me:

```
% alias crd 'awk '\''{$1="";$2="";$3="";$4="";$5="";print}'\'''
```

The alias even seems to be functional:

```
% seq -s\  1 8 | crd
     6 7 8
```

You might also find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38311342/1072112) useful, if your goal is actually to remove columns rather than just nullify content.