# Aliasing awk with printf table

Tags: awk, printf, alias, tcsh

I'm relatively new to Unix, and I can't figure out how to properly define this alias in a **tcsh shell**:

```
alias awkprc 'awk '\''BEGIN { format = "%-8s %8s %15s %15s\n"
                          printf format, "dx", "dz", "CD", "CL" }
                        { printf format, $1, $2, $6, $8 }'\'' '
```

I have a txt file with 18 columns of data, and I want to neatly print the 1st, 2nd, 6th, and 8th columns. I perform this action frequently, hence the alias to a much shorter command, awkprc, that will go in my tcsh profile.

I tried various combinations of escaping certain quotes, suggested here: [Unix 'alias' fails with 'awk' command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24245661/unix-alias-fails-with-awk-command), but I get the error of unmatched ' or missing } or ignoring excess arguments, etc. I have provided a clearer version of my code without all of my attempts at fixing the problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Escaping double quotes with tcsh alias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/382734/escaping-double-quotes-with-tcsh-alias)

Comment: the second answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/22162764) shows various cases of escaping... another suggestion would be to use `bash` which has saner rules unless you have to use `tcsh` for other reasons